# Menu with custom attributes

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-menu

I want to make menu (for NavigationDrawer) with:

- every item - user component (extends `LinearLayout`)
- map menu via xml menu file
- "put" all this into `ListView` (adapter)

looks that it's possible to add custom attributes to menu items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:custom   ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:title="Login"
        custom:description="TEST"/>
   .....
```

but i have no idea how to create an adapter for that and get custom attributes in `getView()`

**UPDATE**
I've create adapter and pass menu to it

```
PopupMenu p  = new PopupMenu(this, null);
Menu menu = p.getMenu();
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu); 
... new AdapterMenu(getApplicationContext(),menu);
```

so now i need to gets my custom attributes from `MenuItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked `MenuInflater` code, the main idea of this class - gets `menu.xml` and parse it to object that implements `menu`.  so, as `menu` has certain structure - the only way i found - create custom `Menu` and `MenuInflater` classes